# csv.DictReader prints out only obj

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

For some reason the following code **only prints out  `<csv.DictReader object at 0x7f2ee79531c0>`**. This is what states on the Python official website but for some reason it doesn't work here, neither with data = `csv.DictReader(file)`  nor data = `csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=','`).
The file `data.csv`  and the code is structered as follows. **Where is the error?**

data.csv's structure:

```
col1, col2, col3
val1, val2, val3
```

The code:

```
file_path = r'data.csv'
    with open(file_path) as file:
        data = csv.DictReader(file)
    print(data)
```

Comment: The DictReader is iterable, so you can get the data using for example `data = list(csv.DictReader(file))`

Comment: What kind of a output do you want?

Answer (score 0):

In the example we find in the docs, they're using a *for-loop* to iterate over the [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) object (*see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)*). So, you need to do the same and you might also want to turn on `skipinitialspace` in order to ignore the spaces after the delimiter (`,`).

```
file_path = r'data.csv'

with open(file_path) as file:
    data = csv.DictReader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in data:
        print(row)
        
    #another variant
    # print(*data)
```

Output :

```
{'col1': 'val1', 'col2': 'val2', 'col3': 'val3'}
{'col1': 'val4', 'col2': 'val5', 'col3': 'val6'} # <-- in case you have more rows
{'col1': 'val5', 'col2': 'val6', 'col3': 'val7'} # <-- in case you have more rows
...
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a skipinitialspace parameter but was solved with the for loop thanks